# Ada - traversing a list - what approach should I use?

Tags: recursion, ada, dijkstra, breadth-first-search

I am working on an ADA project. Essentially I created a list and a list of lists.

So suppose I have a list like A -> B -> D -> E -> F, it means that the tower A is connected to tower B, D, E and F.

Now I also need to have a list to store all the main towers. So suppose I have A ->B -> D -> E -> F, and I have C->X->Y->Q, and E->P->R, the list of lists should be like:

A-> C-> E ( essentially the list of all the main nodes).
As mentioned above, I have a list and its connections. and Now i need to traverse these lists to find out if a connection is possible. For example: I have A ->B -> D -> E -> F, and I have C->X->Y->Q, and E->P->R. If i am asked is A ->R possible answer should be true. Since A -> E -> R. 
My doubt is what approach should I use? BFS? Recursion? What will be the best one?

Answer (score 1):

Nested `for/of` loop? Something like this:

```
Function Exists( Target, Source : Node ) return boolean is
begin
    if Target = Source then
        return True;
    else
        for List of Source loop
            for Item of List loop
                if Item = Target then
                    return True;
                end if;
            end loop;
        end loop;
    end if;

    return false;
end Exists;
```

Or, if you're using the Vector for container there's this function:

```
 function Contains
   (Container : Vector;
    Item      : Element_Type) return Boolean;
```

which you would apply like so:

```
Package Inner_List is new Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Vectors(
                    Index_Type   => Positive,
                    Element_Type => Integer
                     );
Package Outer_List is new Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Vectors(
                    Index_Type   => Positive,
                    Element_Type => Inner_List.Vector,
                    "="          => Inner_List."="
                     );

Function Exists( Item : Integer; List : Outer_List.Vector ) return boolean is
begin
    for Items of List loop
        if Items.Contains(Item) then
            return true;
        end if;
    end loop;

    return false;
End Exists;
```

Comment: It looks helpful. The scenario here is that I am using a generic list as a list. I have defined it. It was a part of the assignment. So I have a ListofLists that contains all main towers and each tower has its own list of connections.
So my doubt is that If i open A->B->C->... I reach Bm then I will need to traverse all the connections of B and so on and so forth.
Correect?

Comment: Shark8: While requests for homework help are welcome here so long as it's upfront--as it clearly is for gkamani2011--an SO answer ought to *help guide* the asker to the answer, rather than provide most of the homework solution.  Just sayin'.

Comment: Given the OP's need to use an 18-year old dialect of Ada, I think this answer will provide guidance rather than a solution...